# .onDelete not calling function swiftUI

Tags: swift, list, function, swiftui

I am trying to delete members of a core data object array in a list. I am using the swipe to delete built in function to do this (.onDelete) however when I debug my code (which does not show any errors) It doesn't call the function at all (hits none of my breakpoints). There are no errors.

I've Tried many different implementations of .onDelete but none of them seem to actually be triggering .onDelete.

Here is my code

```
//
//  FilteredList.swift
//  Workout
//
//  Created by Kaden Thompson on 3/9/22.
//

import SwiftUI
struct FilteredList: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest var fetchRequest: FetchedResults<Workout>
    var filter: String
    init(filterIn: String) {
        filter = filterIn
        _fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Workout>(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.order, order: .reverse)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "type = %@", filterIn))
    }
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
        List() {
            ForEach(fetchRequest, id: \.self) { workout in
                let dateString: String = workout.date ?? ""
                let dateStringTitleStep = dateString.firstIndex(of: " ")!
                let dateStringTitle: String = String(dateString[...dateStringTitleStep])
                let dateStringTime: String = String(dateString[dateStringTitleStep...])
                let weight: String = workout.weight ?? ""
                let reps: String = workout.rep ?? ""
                if (workout.last){

                    Text(dateStringTitle).font(.title).fontWeight(.bold).padding(.vertical, 20.0)
                }
                HStack{
                    
                    let displayString: String = "Time: " + dateStringTime.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
                    Text(displayString).bold()
                    Spacer()
                    if(filter == "Elliptical"){
                        let displayString2: String = "Time: " + weight + "\nResistance: " + reps
                        Text(displayString2)
                    }
                    else{
                        let displayString2: String = "Weight: " + weight + "\nReps: " + reps
                        Text(displayString2)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteWorkouts)
            }

        .navigationTitle(filter.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: " "))
        .navigationBarItems(leading: Image(filter).resizable().frame(width:40, height:40, alignment: .center).cornerRadius(20))
        
        }

    }
    func deleteWorkouts(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for offset in offsets {
            // find this book in our fetch request
            let workout = fetchRequest[offset]

            // delete it from the context
            moc.delete(workout)
        }

        // save the context
        try? moc.save()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be due to the

```
  if (workout.last){..}
```

You could try using

```
if (workout.last){..} else { 
  HStack {...} 
}
```

Or you could try wrapping the inside of the `ForEach` in a `VStack`, such as:

```
 ForEach(fetchRequest, id: \.self) { workout in
    VStack {
     ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: Tried both of these solutions and neither seem to fix the issue. Additionally, I tried fully commenting out the if statement and that did not fix it either